# Hibernate code not work on live server but work on localhost

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, compiler-errors

I am facing problem in Hibernate.My code is work on local server but not on live server.I am using

```
    public void saveEmployee(Emp employee) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(employee);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

for data save. and for HibernateUtil :

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory
 * object.
 *
 * @author Jitendra
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
        // config file.
        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }
```

}

use this code.

and error on stacktrace is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javainfinite.DAOImpl.HibernateUtil
at javainfinite.DAOImpl.EmployeeDaoImpl.showAllEmployees(EmployeeDaoImpl.java:37)
at Controller.EmployeeController.doPost(EmployeeController.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:285)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2376)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] the stack trace into the question instead of posting a screenshot?

Comment: add the full stack trace (with all caused by exceptions)

Comment: where you are putting your hibernate configuration file?

Comment: insight default packege

Comment: That message actually is quite clear: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javainfinite.DAOImpl.HibernateUtil" - your class `HibernateUtil` (which I assume is a inner class of `javainfinite.DAOImpl` as per the name) is not found. I assume there's either a problem with the packaging or the classpath so you should check that.

Comment: Actually that code work on my local glassfish server fine but on apache server it create this problem. I follow this tutorial for hibernate start: 
http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/hibernate-tutorial.html

Comment: One more thing where i initialize class javainfinite.DAOImpl.HibernateUtil.This my second project in which i am not using Hibernate just because of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error a couple of days ago. A "NoClassDefFoundError" Exception tells you that your class isn't published by your compiler/builder. Therefore it is not available on your live system.

In my case I wanted to publish an imported java class to a tomcat server. My solution was to adapt the deployment descriptor for the tomcat and add the imported class to publish it to the library folder.

Comment: Could you show/explain me how can i solve it exactly, if i follow same process like you.

Comment: I work with the Eclipse IDE. There you can right click on your project and go to properties. Choose "Deployment Assembly". There you must add all jars which should be published to the server (e.g. for Tomcat to the "WEB-INF/lib" folder).

Answer (score 0):

Remote Mysql Database Access
Try adding your ip in Remote Mysql in CPanel works for me